# Android frame animation delays the navigation drawer speed

Tags: android-layout, navigation-drawer, android

I am using the navigation drawer. I want to use a frame animation as background in my main activity with the navigation drawer. 
But the navigation drawer opening and closing speed becomes slow when frame animation is started. So I tried the following:

```
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            frameAnimation.start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            frameAnimation.stop();
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
```

This code does the close drawer in a smooth way. But opening still causes some delay. Is there any way to sort it.

Answer (score 0):

Try giving a small delay to the animation stop and start calls. You can experiment with the delay value. Using 450ms here.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        frameAnimation.stop();
    }
},450);

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        frameAnimation.start();
    }
},450);
```

Comment: No it didn't work. The problem happens only during onDrawerOpened as the frameanimation doesn't stop before onDrawerOpened is called. Is there a way to call onDraweropened function after stopping the frameanimation.